# Does Magento automatically convert a guest's old order to his new account?

Tags: customer, customer-account

Suppose a guest has 10 orders with his email id `xx@yy.com`.
Later he registered as a customer. Does Magento automatically convert his old order to his new account, or do we need to do this manually?

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have write a script and excute it.

You can create a file called assign_order.php with the following code and upload at your magento root directory and run this file with the www.domain.com/assign_order.php

```
<?php 
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    umask(0);
    Mage::init();

    $toCustomer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail('xx@yy.com');

    $orders_inc_ids = array('10000001','10000002','10000003','10000004','10000005');

    foreach($orders_inc_ids as $order_inc_id){
        $orderbyid = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_inc_id); // here $order_inc_id contains ur order's increment id
        $orderbyid->setCustomerId($toCustomer->getId());
        $orderbyid->setCustomerFirstname($toCustomer->getFirstname());
        $orderbyid->setCustomerLastname($toCustomer->getLastname());
        $orderbyid->setCustomerEmail($toCustomer->getEmail());
        $orderbyid->save(); 
    }
?>
```

for more information on the how to assign guest orders to customers refer my blog http://pradeepsanku.com/2014/04/30/assign-magento-order-to-customer/

Comment: so you are saying , magento doesn't do that automatically right !

Comment: their is no default feature

Answer (score 2):

First, linking just by email has pitfalls. You could link order to customers mistakenly and cause issues. That aside, this is a generic linking script that would link all guest orders to customer accounts.

```
<?php
// Initialize environment
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::init();

// Get the order collection resource
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection $collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

// Filter to orders without a customer
$collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('null' => true));

// Inner-join to customer table via email
$collection->join(
    array('customer' => 'customer/entity'),
    'main_table.customer_email = customer.email',
    array('linked_customer_id' => 'entity_id')
);

// Limit to same website if configured that way
/** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Config_Share $sharingConfig */
$sharingConfig = Mage::getSingleton('customer/config_share');
if ($sharingConfig->isWebsiteScope()) {
    // Give some feedback about the process
    echo "Limiting linking to website scope.\n";

    // Inner-Join orders to stores to get access to the website_id
    $collection->join(
        array('store' => 'core/store'),
        'main_table.store_id = store.store_id',
        array()
    );

    // Filter customers by using joined website_id as the limiter
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('store.website_id = customer.website_id');
}

// Limit processing run size to 100 records
$collection->setPageSize(100);

// Track the number of linked/updated records
$count = 0;

// Give some feedback about the process
echo sprintf("Attempting to link %d orders.\n\n", $collection->count());

// Loop over all the candidate orders
foreach ($collection as $order) {
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
    // Give some feedback about the process
    echo sprintf('Trying to link order (%s) to customer (%s)... ', $order->getIncrementId(), $order->getCustomerEmail());
    try {
        // Change the order to being linked to a customer record
        $order->setCustomerId($order->getData('linked_customer_id'));
        $order->setCustomerIsGuest(false);

        // Add a comment on the order to record that the order was linked to a customer
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically linking order to customer by email address');

        // Save changes
        $order->save();

        // Give some feedback about the process
        echo sprintf("Succeeded.\n");

        // Increment the counter
        $count++;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Give some feedback about the process
        echo sprintf("Failed! '%s'\n", $e->getMessage());
    }
}

// Give some feedback about the process
echo sprintf("Linked %d orders.\n\n", $count);
```